# Как связать React с Node js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

есть фронтенд(недоделанный еще) небольшого интернет магазина на реакт редакс, хочу написать сервер на node js, но никогда с этим не работал.Как связать реакт с нодой и если есть какие то туториалы то буду рад ссылкам

Answer (score 1):

На словах:

> Приложение на клиенте запрашивает данные с API сервера посредством ajax-запросов и обрабатывает ответы.

Схематично:

```
React+Redux app <---ajax---> Node.js API server
```

Статьи:
[Как слать ajax-запрос с Реакт приложения?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)
[Как обрабатывать запрос на nodejs сервере?](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html)